# Remover tudo antes da primeira ocorrência de um palavra R gsub regex

Tags: r

Isso é tão simples mas não consigo achar a resposta! Gostaria de eliminar tudo antes da primeira ocorrência da palavra "que" de uma string:

O que eu estou fazendo:

```
v <- c("blabla que 1", "blabla que eu Boqueirão que")
gsub(".*que", "", v)
# [1] " 1"   "irão"
```

O resultado que eu queria era "1" e "eu Boqueirão que" . quando eu tento .*^que o comando não surte efeito. 
Agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: Se você der um espaço depois de `que` irá funcionar: `gsub(".*que ", "", v)`. Mas deve existir uma solução mais elegante que essa.

Comment: esse era um exemplo, mas a realidade o meu banco é composto por diversas frases onde o "que" aparece diversas vezes, então essa solução não funciona pra mim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perguntei no stackoverflow em inglês e tive a resposta:

Para manter o "que" `sub(".*?(que)", "\\1", x)` e para não manter o "que" `sub(".*?que", "", x)`

Comment: Apenas para fins explicativo: O `?` após o `*` na regex torna o padrão não-guloso. Isso significa que ele ficará satisfeito com o primeiro encontro que tem e por isso resolve o problema do exemplo da pergunta.